# Instantiating objects from file using Java Stream

Tags: java, arrays, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am in the process of learning about Java 8 Stream API, and there was something I'm trying out that I simply can't get to work. Essentially I have a file containing Strings in the following manner:

0132435,John,Doe,30000.00

Where the first part is an Employee ID, the second is a First name, Third is a Last name, and fourth is yearly salary all separated by commas. I am trying to read this file line by line, pass the entire line to a static method called parse, which will instantiate each Employee, then return that employee, then I want to save all these employees to some kind of list or array so that I can analyze the data. I am trying to do all this with Java stream, but I am having difficulty and don't know why my code does not want to compile. Please keep in mind I am very new at this, Thank you in advance. You can find the code for the stream and parse method below.

parse method

```
public static Employee parse(String s) 
    { 
        String[] empData = s.split(","); 
        Employee newEmp = new Employee(Integer.parseInt(empData[0]), empData[1], empData[2], BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(empData[3]))); 
        
        return newEmp;
    }
```

stream attempt

```
//try with resources 
try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))){ 
    stream.forEach(Employee::parse).collect(Collectors.toList());
} 
catch(IOException e) 
{ 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That is CSV (Comma-Separated-Values) data, so forget about Java Streams and **use a CSV parser**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you need to use `map` to get a stream of `Employee`s you can then collect:

```
List<Employee> employees = 
    Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)).map(Employee::parse).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: While this one-liner looks nice, abdcg was right to put the Stream in a try-with-resources statement, since the Stream is backed by an open file.